# Surface integral - Incorrect orientation

Tags: calculus, integration, divergence-operator

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be compact and with a smooth boundary, such that $(0, 0) \in \mathring\Omega$.

Let $u: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $u(x, y) = \log(x^2+y^2)$.

We want to show that $\int_{\partial \Omega}\langle\nabla u, N\rangle = 4\pi $ where $N$ is the outwards facing normal to the integration region.

**What I tried:**

First I calculated the gradient and the divergence -

$\nabla u = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2} \\ \frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}\end{pmatrix}$

$\Delta u = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2} = 0$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(0, \epsilon) \subset \mathring \Omega$, and define $\Omega'= \Omega \setminus B(0, \epsilon)$. Inside $\Omega'$ we have that $\nabla u$ is a continuously differentiable vector field, and so divergence theorem can be applied.

Using divergence theorem:

$$0 = \int_{\Omega'}\Delta u = \int_{\partial \Omega'}\langle\nabla u, N\rangle = \int_{\partial \Omega}\langle\nabla u, N\rangle + \int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}\langle\nabla u, N\rangle$$

And so overall, $\int_{\partial \Omega}\langle\nabla u, N\rangle = - \int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}\langle\nabla u, N\rangle$

**So all we need to do is calculate the integral over the surface of the sphere.**

The outwards facing normal to the surface of the sphere centered at zero is just the radius, so we should have that $N = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x}{\epsilon} \\ \frac{y}{\epsilon}\end{pmatrix}$, where we divided so it's normalized length 1.

And now:

$$\int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}\langle\nabla u, N\rangle = \int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}\langle\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2} \\ \frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x}{\epsilon} \\ \frac{y}{\epsilon}\end{pmatrix}\rangle = \int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}\langle\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2x}{\epsilon^2} \\ \frac{2y}{\epsilon^2}\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x}{\epsilon} \\ \frac{y}{\epsilon}\end{pmatrix}\rangle = \int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}\frac{2x^2}{\epsilon^3} + \frac{2y^2}{\epsilon^3} = \frac{2}{\epsilon^3}\int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}\epsilon^2 = \frac{2}{\epsilon}\int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}1 = \frac{2}{\epsilon} \times 2 \pi \epsilon = 4 \pi$$

So the answer should be that $\int_{\partial \Omega}\langle\nabla u, N\rangle = -4\pi$ which is not what we wanted to show.

Where is the mistake? Direction of the normal maybe? why??

Comment: Quick self-check: If $\Omega = B(0,\varepsilon)$  then the equality you got by divergence theorem says $\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \langle \nabla u,N\rangle + \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \langle \nabla u,N\rangle =0$. This does not seem right (given what you are required to prove).

Comment: @Ranc something seems off. You can't have that $\Omega = B(0, \epsilon)$ Because in any case, we must have that the integral over $\Omega$ is opposite of integral over $B(0, \epsilon)$. And the integral over the sphere is definitely not zero.

Comment: Exactly my point, they must have opposite directions. Notice that if you write $\Omega ' = \Omega \setminus B(0,\varepsilon)$ then there are two normals, one for $\Omega$ which points outwards to infinity, and one for $B(0,\varepsilon)$ which points outwards to $(0,0)$.